# How do I solve $(x^3-4x^2+5x-6)/(x^2-x-6)=4$ algebraically?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do I solve $\frac {(x^3-4x^2+5x-6)}{(x^2-x-6)=4}$ algebraically?

I tried:

$4(x^2-x-6)=x^3-4x^2+5x-6$

$4x^2-4x-24=x^3-4x^2+5x-6$

$x^3-8x^2+9x+18=0$

I don't know how to solve this algebraically.

Comment: Use the rational root test to discover a root $r$. Divide the polynomial by $(x-r)$ to get a quadratic. Factor the quadratic to obtain the other two roots.

Comment: You have to be careful multiplying through because $x^2-x-6$ may be equal to zero.

Answer (score 3):

$$x^3-4x^2+5x-6 = (x-3)(x^2-x+2)$$
$$x^2-x-6 = (x-3)(x+2)$$
so the equation becomes: $$\frac{x^2-x+2}{x+2} =4 $$
$$x^2-x+2=4x+8$$
$$x^2-5x-6=0$$
$$(x-6)(x+1)=0$$
$x=6$ or $-1$

Comment: Thanks, how did you see that $x^3−4x^2+5x−6$ was equal to (x−3)(x^2−x+2) so quickly?

Comment: @Khas, you can apply the Factor Theorem. Noting that given $h(x)=x^3-4x^2+5x-6$, $h(3)=0\implies x-3$ is a factor.

Answer (score 1):

Use the fact that:
$$\frac{ (x^3-4x^2+5x-6)}{(x^2-x-6)}=(x-3)+\frac{8}{(x+2)} $$
Therefore your solving:
$$ (x-3)+\frac{8}{x+2}=4 \\ x^2-5x-6+8=4x+8\\ x^2-5x-6=0$$
Can you solve this?

Answer (score 1):

$\dfrac{x^3-4x^2+5x-6}{x^2-x-6}=\dfrac{x^3-4x^2+5x-6}{(x-3)(x+2)}$

Now we are going to use Factor Theorem, to determine one of the factors of the numerator, which I call call $h(x)$.

(Note: Just in case you're not familiar with the Factor Theorem, it says that a polynomial $p(x)$ has a factor $(x-c) \iff p(c)=0$ )

We note that $h(3)=0$ and hence $x-3$ is a factor. Then we apply polynomial long division to obtain the other factors. You should get $x^2-x+2$ as your quotient.

$\dfrac{x^3-4x^2+5x-6}{(x-3)(x+2)}=\dfrac{(x-3)(x^2-x+2)}{(x-3)(x+2)}$
.

Then the $(x-3)$'s  will cancel leaving

$\dfrac{(x^2-x+2)}{(x+2)}$

Going back to the original question,

$\dfrac{(x^2-x+2)}{(x+2)}=4 \\
\implies x^2-x+2=4x+8\\
\implies x^2-5x-6=0\\
\implies (x-6)(x+1)=0\\
\implies x=6\text{ or } x=-1$